# How do I build, integrate, and compile java code created by google-protobuf into an Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android-studio, maven-3, protocol-buffers

I have been trying to find a way to integrate java code, generated by google-protobuf's protoc compiler, into an Android Studio project.

```
protoc --java_out=.  Navigation.proto
```

where Navigation.proto contains:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_generic_services = true;
message Navigation {
    string name = 1;
    string url = 2;
} 

service NavRPC {
    rpc putNavigation(Navigation) returns (Navigation);                                                                                                   
};
```

will generate a java class  (Navigation.java), but that class references packages that are not present in the list of libraries (application or external) within Android Studio.

I tried installing the libraries from maven central through the dependencies tab of Project Structure, in Android Studio - but I keep getting error messages that include:

```
Error:(116, 79) error: incompatible types: IOException cannot be converted to String
Error:(261, 36) error: cannot find symbol method parseWithIOException(Parser<NavDrawerElement>,InputStream)
Error:(266, 36) error: cannot find symbol method parseWithIOException(Parser<NavDrawerElement>,InputStream,ExtensionRegistryLite)
Error:(269, 36) error: cannot find symbol method parseDelimitedWithIOException(Parser<NavDrawerElement>,InputStream)
Error:(274, 36) error: cannot find symbol method parseDelimitedWithIOException(Parser<NavDrawerElement>,InputStream,ExtensionRegistryLite)
Error:(278, 36) error: cannot find symbol method parseWithIOException(Parser<NavDrawerElement>,CodedInputStream)
```

Being somewhat new to Java, Android Studio, and Maven -- I am not sure why the errors are happening.   The libraries show up in the external-libraries list but I keep getting unresolved dependencies and errors that would seem to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience with us. I would suggest you remove the current Question content (the preamble about why you posted the Q&A) and replace it with the actual problem you were having, including thing you tried that didn't work. Then you can edit that info out of your Answer and then the Answer content will be more concisely describing the solution. That format will also allow other people to present alternative solutions and allow our moderators to better determine if this question is (for instance) a duplicate.

Comment: I think it is much better! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

One solution I found that actually works for me is to build the google-protobuf jar files and then add to my project libraries.

To build these jar files in MacOS, there were several technologies/packages that had to be installed, configured, and set up correctly.

### JDK 1.8

In MacOSX there is a utility (/usr/libexec/java_home) that can be
used to generate the correct JAVA_HOME environment variable.

I modified my .bashrc file to include:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

If the version of MacOSX installed on your system is based on 10.6,
then the default jdk is version 1.6.  New versions of java and jdk
can be installed from the system preferences/java/java applet, but
once installed, it is still necessary to set JAVA_HOME to point
to the version you want to use.

This is because multiple versions of java can exist on a mac, and
the update utility doesn't try to guess whether or not you want the
latest versions.

### Maven 3.3.8

I use MacPorts for the installation of maven3. In the process of
installing maven3, I had to update ports and all of the related
packages in order to get rid of warnings [regarding out-of-date
packages].

I tried to do the updates installations with 'sudo ports' but kept
running in to problems.  So I ended up using 'sudo bash'.

The commands executed:

```
sudo bash
ports selfupdate
ports install maven3
ports update
```

### google-protobuf

I downloaded protobuf-master from google and built protoc.

I couldn't figure out why the jar files that I expected to be built
weren't, which is what prompted the installation and updates (above)

Once I had the correct jdk and maven was installed, I was able to
change into the java directory and install maven3

The commands executed:

```
mvn3 install
mvn3 package
```

I don't know if/what the differences between install and package -
but it didn't seem to hurt anything by running both.

## Compiling the .proto files

I used a simple .proto file with several message types and the
definition of an RPC service:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_generic_services = true;
message Navigation {
    string name = 1;
    string url = 2;
};

service NavRPC {
    rpc putMessage(Navigation) returns (Navigation);
}
```

### To compile

```
protoc --java_out=$PROJECT_DIR/path/to/package/Navigation.java \
       Navigation.proto
```

## Android Studio

In order to get the protocol-buffer generated class to compile:

I copied these files into my lib directory:

```
protobuf-master/java/core/target/protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar
protobuf-master/java/util/target/protobuf-java-util-3.0.0-beta-2.jar
```

With those files copied, I had to put the name of the package that the source file was being added to.

There are still some questions i have (like how to make Android
Studio automaticall compile a .proto file), but everything works!

Comment: nice answer, btw to automatically compile proto files in your project you can use [protobuf-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin)