# How to integrate a code generator into an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

A lot of libraries/frameworks use some kind of code generator to convert easy-to-read IDL files into source code. A few that I've used with C++ projects include:

- [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf)
- [SMC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smc/)
- [Franca](https://github.com/franca/franca/)

Using CMake, it's relatively straightforward to set up a custom target for running the code generator and make the application target depend on it, so that the generator will be re-run automatically if the IDL file changes.

Now, I need to do the same thing for an Android application, and I'm not finding much help for this online. The closest question I found on this site was:

- [How do I build, integrate, and compile java code created by google-protobuf into an Android Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783527/how-do-i-build-integrate-and-compile-java-code-created-by-google-protobuf-into)

But the OP for that question just wanted to run the code generator *manually* and include it in his project. I've already figured out how to do that, now I want Android Studio/Gradle do it *for* me.

To make the question more concrete, I'm currently running this command to generate `FacialRecognitionContext.java` from the file `FacialRecognition.sm`:

```
$ java ./smc/bin/Smc.jar -java FacialRecognition.sm
```

How can I instruct Gradle to do this for me automatically whenever `FacialRecognition.sm` changes?

#### UPDATE

Further searching led to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820728/simple-protobuf-compilation-with-gradle) and [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@elye.project/simple-android-protobuf-tutorial-with-actual-code-bfb581299f47), both of which seem to imply that the 'best'(?) way to handle `.proto` files is using the [Protobuf Plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin). I have to say, this is rather vexing. When I look at the [sources](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/tree/master/src/main/groovy/com/google/protobuf/gradle) for the protobuf plugin, I see that it contains *nine* Groovy files(?!) Do I *really* need to write an entire SMC *plugin* just to generate a single file?

Comment: How about a bash script that protoc's all the proto files in a folder structure. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949801/how-to-compile-multiple-proto-files-in-single-command & https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883887/794088 should do it)

Comment: @petey, thanks for the links. It looks like I could assemble _most_ of a solution from them. The thing I'm still not sure about is: how do I tell Gradle that my `compileProtos` task depends on, say, `foo.proto`, `bar.proto` and `baz.proto` (or whatever) so that it gets re-run _automatically_ whenever those files have been modified?